# Blank input breaks timer

Tags: javascript

I created a time keeper for work. The timer is static since we have another program recording the time which track on its own, only on the back end. Instead of messaging a manager for the time, I figured I could make this timer.

I have one issue with the script: If you leave the input field blank and you press enter, it returns a blank value and somehow gets through the "NaN:NaN" check:

```
  if (element1 == "NaN:NaN") {

alert("This is not a valid number. Please use the following format: 2:36");
      return document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "50:00"; 

}

else {
return document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = element1;}
}
```

If you type in 1.23 instead of 1:23, using a decimal instead of a colon, the script will break and say "NaN:NaN". The NaN check does not seem to cover a blank or null value.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>



.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #060606;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #000000;
}

.button:hover {background-color: #101010}

.button:active {
  background-color: ##000000    ;
  box-shadow: 0 3px #080808;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
}
#time2 { width: 90px; height: 390px; border: 1px solid #999999; padding: 5px; }

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;

}


.Wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}



.Input {
  position: relative;
  align: center;
}


.Input-text::placeholder {
  color: #B0BEC5;
}

.Input-text:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.8rem 1.6rem var(--colorPrimary600);
}


</style>


<script type="text/javascript">


    function setTimes(info) {
  var sel = info.split('|');
  document.getElementById('time1').value = sel[0];
  document.getElementById('time2').value = sel[1];

}

</script>
<title> Personal Time Keeper</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<br><br>
<div align="center"><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<font size="50" face="Verdana" color="white">
<h1 id="time1"><script>document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "50:00"</script>
</h1>

    <font size="3" face="verdana" color="gray">

    <input type="text" id="time2" class="Input-text" placeholder="Ex: 2:36">


</h1><br>
<button class="button"  onclick="document.getElementById('time1').innerHTML = timeAddSub('time1','time2',false);" >
Enter
</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

Number.prototype.padDigit = function() { return (this < 10) ? '0'+this : ''+this; }

function timeAddSub(id1, id2, flag) {  // flag=true to add values and flag=false to subtract values
  var p = document.getElementById(id1);

  var tt1 = p.textContent;  if (tt1 == '') { return ''; }
  var t1 = tt1.split(':');
  var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  if (tt2 == '') { return ''; }
  var t2 = tt2.split(':');
  tt1 = Number(t1[0])*60+Number(t1[1]);
  tt2 = Number(t2[0])*60+Number(t2[1]);
  var diff = 0;  if (flag) { diff = tt1 + tt2; } else { diff = tt1 - tt2; }
  t1[1] = Math.abs(diff % 60).padDigit();                        // form minutes
  t1[0] = Math.abs(Math.floor(parseInt(diff / 60))).padDigit();  // form hours
  var tt1 = '';  if (diff < 0) { tt1 = '-'; } 
  // check for negative value
var element1 = tt1+t1.join(':');


  if (element1 == "NaN:NaN") {

alert("This is not a valid number. Please use the following format: 2:36");
      return document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "50:00"; 

}

else {

return document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = element1;}

}
</script>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing "NaN:NaN" to null, to "". I am not sure if I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: Please limit the code to the part needed to reproduce the issue. I suppose all that CSS is unrelated to the problem, and parts of the code could also be left out. Making it short will increase the probability that someone will want to analyse it.

Comment: Agreed, please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Firstly you should validate input is not empty

Can you change `var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  if (tt2 == '') { return ''; }`

---

```
var tt2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;  
if (tt2 == '') { 
  alert("This is not a valid number. Please use the following format: 2:36");
 return document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = "50:00"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are quite correct about the "NaN:NaN"-check being too specific for the task.
We can however resolve this issue by adding some regex to test with instead.
The following code will evaluate if the value is in a valid format rather than checking for one type of errogenous result.

```
var timePattern = new RegExp("[0-9]{1,2}[:.][0-9]{1,2}")
if(!timePattern.test(element1)){
    //Here we do error handling code
}
```

There also seems to be some room for further improvements here.
For example you might want to make '`.`' into a valid input separator by changing your split functions into one that makes use of regex instead.

```
var t1 = tt1.split(/:|\./);
```

This one will now split on either colons or periods.
Since the code later joins elements using specifically colon, separating on other characters here should not result in any issues later on.